# RavenDB Migration: update property from string to array of strings

Tags: .net, ravendb, data-migration

I have a collection of documents named Actions. Action in db looks like this:

```
{
    "Name": "Name1",
    "ActionType": "typeA"
}
```

I need to migrate all my Actions so ActionType property would contain an array of strings:

```
{
    "Name": "Name1",
    "ActionType": ["typeA"]
}
```

I don't want to create any converters in my project like mentioned [here](http://ayende.com/blog/66563/ravendb-migrations-rolling-updates).
That should be a simple utility which can be run separately.

The idea is to load all documents, made necessary changes and save them (like [here](http://blog.tnwdevlabs.com/2013/07/24/RavenDb-Data-Migrations-Using-RavenJobject/)). My current code looks like that but it doesn't work correctly:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Raven.Client;
using Raven.Client.Document;
using Raven.Client.Linq;
using Raven.Json.Linq;

namespace RavenDbMigration
{
    public class SimpleMigrator
    {
        private readonly IDocumentStore _documentStore;

        public SimpleMigrator(IDocumentStore documentStore)
        {
            _documentStore = documentStore;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            using (IDocumentSession session = _documentStore.OpenSession())
            {
                var fullRavenIdsList = new List<string> {"1", "2", "3"};

                RavenJObject[] ravenJObjects = session.Load<RavenJObject>(fullRavenIdsList); // Problem here - ravenJObjects contains 3 null values instead of actions
                foreach (var ravenJObject in ravenJObjects)
                {
                    var results = ravenJObject["Actions"] as RavenJArray;
                    if (results != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var result in results)
                        {
                            if (result != null && result.ContainsKey("ActionType"))
                            {
                                var actionTypes = new List<string>();

                                var actionType = result.Value<string>("ActionType");
                                if (actionType != null)
                                {
                                    actionTypes.Add(actionType);
                                }
                                result["ActionType"] = new RavenJArray(actionTypes);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                session.SaveChanges();
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

I use RavenDB.Client of version 2.5.2700.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch your document collection "Actions" either via the Raven Studio or via code.

```
this.ActionType = [this.ActionType];
```

This will result in a document looking like this:

```
"Name": "Name1",
"ActionType": [
  "typeA"
]
```

[image: Patch in Raven Studio]
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a new field with a type of List   and then migrate data into the list,  also you have no paging, so you would need to page to get all data for this to work for all records.

afterwards,  you delete the old, single string property from your model,  then when your data does any more updates etc, this property will be removed.

OR

You do it how they told you to do it, on the link provided,  The guy who created that post, owns RavenDB  and knows what he is talking about, and if he says this is the best way,  You can usually guarantee that it is.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody would be interested in how to perform this migration from code here is the sample code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Raven.Client;
using Raven.Client.Linq;
using Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Raven.Json.Linq;

namespace RavenDbMigration
{
    public class SimpleMigrator
    {
        private readonly IDocumentStore _documentStore;
        private readonly int _pageSize;

        public SimpleMigrator(IDocumentStore documentStore, int pageSize = 128)
        {
            _pageSize = pageSize;
            _documentStore = documentStore.Initialize();
        }

        public void Run(string databasName)
        {
            var pageIndex = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                using (var session = _documentStore.OpenSession(databasName))
                {
                    var ravenJObjects = session.Query<RavenJObject>().Skip(_pageSize * pageIndex).Take(_pageSize);

                    if (!ravenJObjects.Any()) break;

                    foreach (var ravenJObject in ravenJObjects)
                    {
                        var ravenJTokenActionType = ravenJObject.SelectToken("ActionType");

                        if (ravenJTokenActionType == null || ravenJTokenActionType.Type != JTokenType.String) continue;

                        var actionType = ravenJTokenActionType.ToString();

                        var actionTypes = new List<string> { actionType };

                        ravenJObject["ActionType"] = new RavenJArray(actionTypes);

                        //// In case you want to rename property
                        //ravenJObject["ActionTypes"] = new RavenJArray(actionTypes);
                        //ravenJObject.Remove("ActionType");
                    }

                    session.SaveChanges();
                }

                pageIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```